# Get list of images missing dimension tags

Tags: regex, search, dreamweaver

I am trying to generate a sitewide report of images missing width= and height= tags. I thought Dreamweaver (CS4) would have this option, but it only has the report of missing ALT tag. So it seems a regex report might be the only way, but I have hit a bit of a snag (I am not fluent in regex). The regex I have works on a single test page: I have four images and removed the width and height calls from one - the regex Find in Dreamweaver only results in *that* image. But when I set the Find to the entire site, it results in every image, especially those *with* a width tag.

This is the regex that I put into Dreamweaver's search box:

```
<img (.*) ((?!\bwidth\b).) (.*) />
```

1. Am I missing something from the regex?
2. Or is there a different tool that can do this search?

Any help or insight would be appreciated ... Thanks

David

Answer (score 0):

@David

### Regex

Not a full answer to your question but you can use RegExr (http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) to try out your expressions, I have found that tool helpful in the past.

### Alternative

You could also try using the Unix grep command combining a search for img tags with an inverted search for width=. It would looking something like

`cat file.txt | grep "img" | grep -v "width="`

Sorry I can't post that as a comment, I don't have enough points.